# gulp-react. How to compile and save all folders

Tags: gulp, reactjs

I use [gulp-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-react) to compile jsx to js. I need to save folder structure while compiling.

The code below works good for single folder of all files, but I need dumanic **destination**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var react = require('gulp-react');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src('template.jsx')
        .pipe(react())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist')); // in this line need dumanic destination
});
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: You should add this as an answer and accept it, or delete your question. Also, you should be able to use ``'./public/js/**/*'`` to save your self an extra `*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved like this

gulp.src('./public/js/**/*.*')